# Broken external hard drive

Tags: external-hard-drive

My external hard drive fell on the floor. The exit on the hard drive where the USB wire is attached snapped off, so I can't get any power to it!

Do you know of any companies who receives broken external hard drives, and either repair it or collect the data on it over to another hard drive?

Comment: Try googling for a hard drive  data recovery/data recovery service (a couple possibilities showed up in my area when I did)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming only the casing is damaged: You can open the external case and check which drive is inside. Then either

1. Mount the drive in another computer (usually in a desktop)
2. use an external drive dock (see image below)
3. get a new external case.

[image: Image of an external dock]

Regardless of choice, first check the drive. The USB plug might not be the only thing which broke when it hit the floor.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose the hard disk is still in working conditions. You can get a cheap hard disk casing (assuming your hard disk is 2.5") from [Amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000UTQOEW) or somewhere else. And even if it's a 3.5" hard disk, you can use with particular casing as well.